# .Net 7 Jwt Authorization always return error 500 in the server method decorated with [Authorize] Attribute

Tags: jwt, authorization, blazor-webassembly

This is the jwt builder method in jwt service:

```
public async Task<string> BuildToken([FromBody] string userName)
{                    
    //AppUser user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);
    UserData user = new UserData();            
    var claims = new List<Claim>()
    {
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, userName),
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id.ToString()),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
    };
    //var userClaims = await userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user);
    var userRoles = user.Roles; //await userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);            
    foreach (var userRole in userRoles)
    {
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, userRole));                
    }
    // Creates a key from our private key that will be used in the security algorithm next
    var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["Jwt:Key"]));

    // Credentials that are encrypted which can only be created by our server using the private key
    var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);           

    var token = new JwtSecurityToken(_config["Jwt:Issuer"],
        _config["Jwt:Audience"],
        claims, 
        expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(double.Parse(_config["Jwt:ExpireTime"])),
        signingCredentials: creds);

    // return the token in the correct format using JwtSecurityTokenHandler
    return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);         
}
```

And this is program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddTransient<IJwtTokenService, JwtTokenService>();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        //ValidateIssuer = true,
        //ValidateAudience = true,
        //ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        //ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
        //ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey
        (Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"])),       
    };
});
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

var app = builder.Build();
```

And the configure method:

```
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseSession();
app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllers();
app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

app.Run();
```

The token is built and everything works in the client side except serverside that I have this method in web api:

```
[HttpGet("GetKeyIV")]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer")] // or [Authorize] is not working
public async Task<TokenDTO> GetKeyIV()
{           
    string strings = $"{_config["Cookie:Key"]}, {_config["Cookie:IV"]}";
    return new TokenDTO() { Token = strings };
}
```

This is a blazor wasm project and client side works but serverside not. how to get the authorize attribute that always returns error 500 to work?

In the client I have:

```
_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {token}");
```

And I can verify the token is in my HttpClient before the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `MiddleWares` order is incorrect and should be as follows

```cs
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseSession();

app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllers();
app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

app.Run();
```

Comment: with this solution I get a better error than 500 (it gets error 401 unauthorized). but still there is an error.

Comment: I enabled the disabled lines (commented) previously (such as //ValidateIssuer) and now it works.